# how can i handle the relations beetween products attributes and values?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, relational-database, laravel-livewire

i'm working on a Laravel/Livewire project

there are some products and services in this platform that user can order them.

the price of these products and services are changeable by their attributes . like size,color,quality and....

and i made a Many To Many relation between products and attributes.

but a can't handle it in my view where user should select that attributes before ordering

and my for each loop return wrong data .   and i get this error :

Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object .

my migration :

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('attr_product', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->foreignId('attr_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('value')->nullable();
            $table->string('price')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

product model :

```
public function attr(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Attr::class)->withPivot(['value','price'])->withTimestamps();
    }
```

attr model:

```
public function product(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['value','price'])->withTimestamps();
    }
```

my controller :

```
 class SingleProduct extends Component
{
    public $product;

    public function mount($id){
        $this->product=Product::with('attr')->findOrFail($id);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.front.product.single-product')->extends('layouts.Default')->section('content');
    }
}
```

my loop in blade :

```
  @foreach($product->attr as $attr)
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-3">
                                    <h6 class="mb-2 text-black">{{$attr->title}}</h6>
                                    <select class="custom-select shadow-none">
                                         @foreach($attr as $av)
                                        <option value="{{$av->pivot->price}}">{{$av->pivot->value}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                 


 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

before `@foreach` add

```
@php
dd($product)
@endphp
```

You can troubleshoot your $product Model and relations

Answer (score -1):

The right syntax for `withPivot` should be parameters separated by comma, try this:

product model

```
public function attr(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Attr::class)
               ->withPivot('value','price')
               ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

attr model:

```
public function product(){

        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)
               ->withPivot('value','price')
               ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: what's different ??? i used , in withPivot  see my codes again

Comment: my relations are correct because it works in my admin panel  where admin add attr and allocate it to a product

Comment: you used `withPivot(['value', 'price'])` as array parameter, while the correct syntax is `withPivot('value', 'price')` as different parameters

Comment: "correct syntax" for withPivot is `array|mixed $columns`